# What do you call the double pipe in javascript, as used in this context?

Tags: javascript

People often write this in order to specify default values:

```
var thing = this || that;
```

which is, AFAIK, the same thing as this:

```
var thing = !!this ? this : that;
```

What do you call the technique used to specify defaults in the first code block?

**NOTE**: I am not asking what a logical OR is called. I am asking what the alternative to ternary notation (as written in the first code block) is called.

Comment: || means OR in javascript

Comment: yes, but OR in the traditional sense evaluates to a boolean. in this case, it evaluates to some arbitrary value

Comment: @DanyJoumaa yes I agree; the terminology "or" is misleading, though I don't know of an alternative. Something like "first truthy" would be better but it sounds pretty goofy.

Comment: From ES5 spec: `NOTE The value produced by a && or || operator is not necessarily of type Boolean. The value produced will always be the value of one of the two operand expressions.` (http://es5.github.io/#x11.11) I think the general thing you're referring to is "short-circuiting", where the first truthy value is returned

Comment: .NET tends to call the short-circuiting OR operator `OrElse`. It's logically different from the JS `||` operator (because it's more type-safe) but I like the name. `this || that` would be read as "*this or else that*". However, it calls the short-circuiting AND operator `AndAlso`, which doesn't sound so good. `this && that` would be read as "*this and also that*", but this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: a sidenote: the `!!` in this context is unnecessary

Comment: MDN quotes `Returns expr1 if it can be converted to true; otherwise, returns expr2` But I can't find a name for it other than `OR` But I do like @Pointy `"first truthy"` :)

Comment: @basilikum it is only to be explicit about the fact that the argument to the ternary operator is of type boolean

Comment: @Pointy—"first truthy" doesn't work since if all the first `n - 1` expressions are falsey, it unconditionally returns the value of the final expression, whether it's truthy or falsey.

Comment: @RobG can you explain more?

Comment: I guess it would be because "first truthy or final expression"

Comment: @RobG oh right; so maybe "first truthy or whatever"

Comment: @Pointy Even better :)

Comment: @p.s.w.g—more like `if this then that`, but not quite… @Pointy—yes. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd call:

```
var a = A || B;
```

**conditional assignment**, since it is effectively:

```
if (!!A) {
  a = A;
} else {
  a = B;
}
```

and it is a replacement for the [conditional operator `: ?`](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.12)

```
var a = A? A : B;
```

It might also be called "logical assignment" since it involves a logical OR expression, but it doesn't seem to fit with what it's doing.

Comment: How about `sheepy` or `lamby` as it is `bar bar`? :)

Comment: Your answer comes the closest to recognizing the intent of my question -- thanks!

Comment: I am uncomfortable with the name "conditional assignment" however, because you can get a non-boolean evaluation without involving assignment.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned elsewhere it is a logical OR.

The evaluation in question is a [short-circuit evaluation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-Circuit_Evaluation).

It might help to look at it like this:

```
if ((foo = bar)) {

} else {
    foo = baz;
}
```

The `if` statement evaluates to the value of `bar`. If bar is false, null etc the evaluation would be false.

---

***Edit: Note:***

It is perfectly valid to evaluate an assignment. If we say:

```
if ((a = b)) { ...
```

note that it is not:

```
if (a === b) { ...
```

the evaluation is done on the result of the assignment. Here it would evaluate to true `if (b)`.

One should however always wrap them in parenthesis. This makes it clear that we are evaluating the assignment and not comparing the variables.

If one do not *like it* that is fair enough, (I'm rather used to it from C), but in this case it is merely for the sake of the answer to the question.

---

In the same way we have:

```
if ((foo = foo)) {

} else {
     foo = baz;
}


var x = false;
console.log((x = x)); // False
```

As such we can say:

```
(x = x) || (x = y)
```

And to make it short:

```
x = (x || y);
```

or shorter:

```
x = x || y;
```

Comment: I understand what an OR statement is; I was just asking what one calls the technique of specifying defaults using the double pipe. Another answerer called it "conditional assignment." Unless you're aware of the official name of this technique, I'm accepting the other answer for now.

Comment: There is an old version of Opera that converts `(a = b)` to `(a == b)` unless wrapped in additional `()`, so `((a = b))` is a good idea. :-)

Comment: @RobG So to avoid that, you are saying that `if ((foo = foo)) {` should really be written `if (((foo = foo))) {` to avoid being bitten? :)

Comment: @DanyJoumaa: By all means :) Liked the name myself.

Comment: @Xotic750—it should be `if ((a = b)){...}` to indicate that assignment is intended and keep ancient Opera happy. :-)

Comment: Aha, ok. I think I'll stick with avoiding assignments in such situations. It doesn't seem to offer any benefit in speed, perhaps fewer lines, and possibly more characters and it can easily be mistaken during reading (IMO). It seems easier to read `assign b to a; if a is truthy then` rather than `if assign b to a afterwhich evaluate that a is truthy then` (it's even harder to put into nice English) :)

Comment: @Xotic750: Yes, it is worth mentioning that this is not something I usually do, but sometimes, due to context and even variable names it makes it clearer what is happening. One place I use it frequently is by asserting function calls like `fopen` in C. E.g. `if (!(fh = fopen(filename, "bw"))) { perror(filename); fprintf(stderr, "Some warning.\n"); return errno; }` – which also might be considered something else then `if ((a = b)) { ... }`. Reading my comments it might sound like I find this a preferred method of assignment, which it is not.

Comment: I've been programming for almost 30 yrs and let me tell you only in JS do I see this kind of frankly out of control, horribly confusing to read/decipher coding.  Also, it's the only language that apparently, despite taking 10 seconds to jsmin your code after you write it, pride itself on this utterly nasty i'll be the first to call it - ULTRA NESTING, where instead of writing functions that can be reused, updated, etc., JS coders feel necessary to instead write every function only usable ONCE, disposable, because it's NESTED within every line of code. Worst language I've ever dealt with.

Comment: In ANY other language, (a = b) || (b = c) is just a syntax error and means nothing unless you put an IF before it to simply boolean compare with the OR operator.....all you have to do is read the actual language docs to see there must seriously be a group of kids with ADHD writing and acting as the overall approvers of the JS language revs, when the docs on the link provided in this post seriously read this:  "If a value can be converted to true, the value is so-called truthy. If a value can be converted to false, the value is so-called falsy.". CONVERTED? TRUTHY? FALSY? How about RETARDEDY?!?

Answer (score -1):

The double pipe is called the 'or' operator.

Comment: I don't think there's a specific name to technique.  Let's call it the  'Double Door'? =]

Comment: I wasn't asking about the double pipe per se; was talking about the technique of specifying defaults using the double pipe

Answer (score -1):

The double pipe is the [Logical OR operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators) in JavaScript.

If the technique had a name I guess it would be "(ab)using the short-circuiting of the logical OR operator"

Comment: But that's the thing - it's really *not* the "logical-OR" operator. It's the "find the first truthy value" operator.

Comment: "find the first truthy value" operator is probably the most accurate name i've heard yet. if you update your answer I'll set it as correct. thanks!